# Getting the MVC textbox value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Good day

I am trying to retrieve the value of a textbox field in MVC using Razor and assign it to a variable to later be passed via ajax to an action controller.
I have tried using .val() but when debugging using Google developer tools I keep getting .val() is not a function. I am not that experienced with jquery right now and would like a little assistance. herre is the coode below.

The Jquery Code

```
$(".RefreshQuantity").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var productToUpdate = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var countToUpdate = $('#txt-id').val();
            if (productToUpdate != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/UpdateQuantity", { "id": productToUpdate, "cartCount": countToUpdate },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } //else {
                        //    $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);  
                        //}

                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal).formatCurrency();
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message).show();
                        setTimeout(function () { $("#update-message").hide(); }, 4000);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');

                    });
            }
        })
```

I am trying to get the value and assign it to the countToUpdate variable,

My Razor code is below

```
 @{int i = 0;}
            @foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
            {
                <tr id="row-@item.OrderCodeID">
                    <td>
                        @*@item.ProductAttribute.Product.ProductImagePath*@
                        <img src="/Images/OnlineStore/ProductImages/@item.ProductAttribute.Product.ProductImagePath"
                             style="border:solid; height: 50px; width: 50px; border-color: #CCCCCC;" alt="@item.ProductAttribute.Product.ProductImagePath" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.ProductAttribute.OrderCodeID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink(item.ProductAttribute.Product.ProductName, "ProductDetails", "Store", new { productId = item.ProductAttribute.ProductID }, null)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @String.Format("{0:c}",@item.ProductAttribute.Product.ProductPrice)
                    </td>
                    @*<td id="item-count-@item.OrderCodeID">
                        @item.Quantity
                    </td>*@
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CartItems[i].Quantity, new { style = "width:50px; text-align:right"})
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" class="RemoveLink btn-success btn-sm" data-id="@item.OrderCodeID" >
                            <i class="fa fa-times">&nbsp;Remove All</i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity btn-success btn-sm" data-id="@item.OrderCodeID" txt-id="CartItems_@(i)__count ">
                            <i class="fa fa-refresh">&nbsp;Update</i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    @*<td>
                        <a href="#" class="RemoveLink btn-success btn-xs" data-id="@item.OrderCodeID">Update</a>
                    </td>*@
                </tr>   
                i++;
            }
```

Please help, been at this for a couple hours.

Comment: If you're getting "`val()` is not a function" (a method that only exists as part of the jQuery library), have you verified that you are in fact including and properly loading the jQuery library? The developer tools should tell you which external scripts have loaded, and any other JS errors.

Comment: Are you referring to `var countToUpdate = $('#txt-id').val();`? You dont have any elements with `id="txt-id"` so it would be undefined.

Comment: The element is down in the Razor code block, int the foreach statement

Comment: txt-id="CartItems_@(i)__count "

Comment: The Jquery library is loaded, as it shows and the variable productToUpdate was defined when I stepped through.

Comment: @PsyChotic, That is not an `id` attribute. You would need `var countToUpdate = $(this).attr('txt-id');` But you really should be doing this using a `data-` attribute

Comment: Also `txt-id="CartItems_@(i)__count"` does not really make sense. Not sure what you really trying to do. Do you want to get the total number of items in the collection or the index of the item in the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` is a function, but only on a jQuery object.  This isn't returning such an object:

```
$('#txt-id')
```

Because it's not finding any matched elements.  That selector is looking for exactly one element with this attribute:

```
id="txt-id"
```

And you don't have any elements with that attribute.  You do have this:

```
txt-id="CartItems_@(i)__count "
```

But I'm not really sure what you're trying to do there or what would use a `txt-id` attribute.  Additionally, that's on an `a` element, which wouldn't have a "value" to be read by the `.val()` function.  And even if you do give that an `id`, that `id` would have to be *unique* in the DOM.  Which you can do in a loop easily enough based on a unique counter or something of that nature, but then you're going to have to account for that dynamic `id` in your jQuery.

You can get a value from a text box (`input type="text"`) using the `.val()` function in jQuery, but you need a selector which identifies the text box you want.  **It looks like the text box is a couple elements away from what you're clicking**, so you might need to get creative.  Perhaps doing a bit of DOM traversal in your selection.

For example (and this is just an example, there are plenty of ways to do it), you might give it a class:

```
new { style = "width:50px; text-align:right", @class = "someClass" }
```

Then in your jQuery you can identify that specific `input` element in relation to the clicked element with something like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.someClass')
```

That basically says: "Starting at the clicked element, find the nearest `tr` ancestor (so you're now in the context of the entire table row), then find child elements with the class `someClass` (which would identify that text box, assuming you don't use that class for anything else).

Comment: I kind of get it as when I step through the code data-text-id is only returning  "countToUpdate: "CartItems_0__count". So I see what you are saying. Basically what I am trying to do is, I have a list of cart items this is what the count variable is for, because I can have a long list of items in the cart and based off where you are at in the loop it chooses that position, if I saying this right.

Comment: @PsyChotic: I'm not really following what you're trying to do.  It looks like the responses so far have a couple of different interpretations of the end goal.  Are you trying to get a value which was assigned to the element from server-side code and doesn't change in the browser, or are you trying to get a user-entered value from the text box?  My answer is based on the latter, which is what I thought you were asking in the question.

Comment: Thanks man for your input, I tried what you suggested and it worked, Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any element with that id in your DOM, you have an anchor with an attribute as `txt-id`, which is the element that you are binding your function to the click event, you should be able to do as follows:

```
$(".RefreshQuantity").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var productToUpdate = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var countToUpdate = $(this).attr("txt-id"); //Here is the change
            if (productToUpdate != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/ShoppingCart/UpdateQuantity", { "id": productToUpdate, "cartCount": countToUpdate },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } //else {
                        //    $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);  
                        //}

                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal).formatCurrency();
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message).show();
                        setTimeout(function () { $("#update-message").hide(); }, 4000);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');

                    });
            }
        })
```

If by any reason you can't get that to work (since `txt-id` is not a standard attribute, you could change it to `data-txt-id` instead):

```
<a href="#" class="RefreshQuantity btn-success btn-sm" data-id="@item.OrderCodeID" data-txt-id="CartItems_@(i)__count ">
    <i class="fa fa-refresh">&nbsp;Update</i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Razor, the text-id is part of an anchor tag. The val() methods works uniquely on forms.

The following should work in most browsers. Use the attribute selector $("[txt-id]") and then get the value of that attribute:

```
`$("[txt-id]").getAttribute("txt-id")`
```